# Android - Salvar e atualizar String enviada de uma atividade para outra

Tags: java, android

//Eu conseguir enviar e receber dois valores diferentes em uma intent

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(checkBox.isChecked())
        {
            String trueThumb_check = "checked_thumb";
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("trueThumbnail", trueThumb_check);
            startActivity(i);
            killAc();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("falseThumbnail", "");
            startActivity(i);
            killAc();
        }

    }
```

//Então recebi valores diferentes:

```
    try {
                Intent thumb_check = getIntent();
                String thumb_thumb = thumb_check.getStringExtra("trueThumbnail");
                if (thumb_thumb.contains("checked_thumb")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "checkBox ativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not checkBox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

//Mas não estou conseguindo salvar o resultado. Ele precisa ser salvo e atualizado quando o checkBox for marcado ou não

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("ch4an.ytheloader", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("trueThumbnail", thumb_thumb);
editor.commit();
```

**EDIT:**
Para sempre que o usuário entrar na tela MainActivity, fique salvo o status que foi enviada da activity de preferências.

Answer (score 0):

Deixe-me ver se entendi, você precisa passar o status da `CheckBox` para outra activity!

**Tente isso:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.putBooleanExtra("checkBoxValue", checkBox.isChecked());
startActivity(i);
```

---

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("checkBoxValue")){
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "checkBox ativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "checkBox não ativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Eu já conseguir passar o status da checkBox. Então recebi corretamente na outra activity. Agora necessito SALVAR e (atualizar) o status da mesma.

Comment: Para sempre que o usuário entrar na tela MainActivity, fique salvo o status que foi enviada da activity de preferências. Entendeu?

Comment: Está emitindo algum erro quando você tenta salvar nas preferências?

Comment: Na verdade, não. Porém quando eu disponho o código a salvar e reinício o app, o Toast não aparece. Entendeu? Sendo que era pra ter salvo a String e ter voltado na averiguação se contém "checked_thumb" na mesma.

Comment: Assim, sucessivamente aparecia o Toast, se tivesse salvo a String e averiguado.

Comment: Na atividade de preferências tá tudo ok! Eu não necessito mais salvar lá. Eu quero salvar na MainActivity. A atividade que foi recebida a String.